# Fail to connect to github and get my account credential using the octokit gem in rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create github OAuth apps in github and install octokit gem in my rails.
But I fail to connect to github and get my account credential using the octokit gem in rails c.

It return this Error message: Octokit::Unauthorized (GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Requires authentication // See: https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user)

My github login and email credential is correct.
Please advice how to solves this error.Thanks.

[rails c screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48mgn.png)